# Sending a string to ActionResult using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am trying to send a string to my ActionResult in the controller. I have followed many tutorials and read hundreds of stackoverflows but can't get it to work. I am trying to send a string with the value of a radiobutton.

My ActionResult code is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Opslaan(string theStatus)
    {
        if(theStatus!= null)
            Database.UpdateAanvraagStatusByGuid(Session["Guid"].ToString(), theStatus);
        return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString);
    }
```

My code to send the variable via AJAX:

```
$("#opslaan").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var theStatus = $('input[name=StatusOptions]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Aanvraag/Opslaan",
        data: theStatus,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                alert("Uw wijzigingen zijn opgeslagen.");
            } else {
                alert(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I click my button called "opslaan" the program does not execute te AJAX. Alerts around it do go off.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked the console or network tab of your browser tools to get more info about the problem?

Comment: @br4d the network tab does say it is sending something but it 404's

Comment: Use `data: { theStatus: theStatus },`

Comment: The Post is being sent but still 404's. Same as without this modification.

Comment: You need to make the change as per my comment anyway, but a 404 means that your url ("/Aanvraag/Opslaan") does not exist - check it! In any case you should never hard code url's  - use `url: '@Url.Action("Opslaan", "Aanvraag")',`

Comment: I was using the .Action method before, but since it wouldnt work i tried this. Changing it back still doesnt work.

Comment: Then manually type that address in your browser - does it still throw the same 404? Who knows - perhaps your using areas and you have not specified the area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit Fabio's answer like this:

```
$("#opslaan").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var theStatus = $('input[name=StatusOptions]:checked').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Aanvraag/Opslaan?theStatus= " + theStatus ,
    //data: { 'theStatus': theStatus } ,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success) {
          alert("Uw wijzigingen zijn opgeslagen.");
        } else {
          alert(result.Message);
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Note the query string at the end of the url property. Even though string IS a nullable type, if you don't have any route configuration like "/Aanvraag/Opslaan/theStatus", the routing system will not find a match.

There are a few things to note here:

- Your original solution DID show an alert, that means a request went to the server, and a response has arrived.
- Fabio's answer didn't work because you (as I guess) don't have any route like `"/Aanvraag/Opslaan/theStatus"`. Even though `string` is a nullable type - so the routing system will allow a string parameter to have no incoming value from the request - the `url` parameter set by the client told the routing system 'Hey please forward me to something that is configured to a url like "/Aanvraag/Opslaan/theStatus"'. I am sure You don't have any route set up with that pattern so the routing system will fail to find a matching Controller/Action method pair, that results in a 404.
- Your original solution didn't cause this problem, because you sent the `theStatus` parameter as data, and your `url` was "/Aanvraag/Opslaan". This means even the default route will be able to find out that the Controller is 'Aanvraag' and the controller is 'Osplaan'. From then on, Model Binding was able to bind your `theStatus` parameter to the action method parameter. (If it wasn't, the proper action method would strill be called, just with a `null` value given to the parameter.) However, your response didn't send any object with property `Success` back, so your `if` statement went to the `else` branch.

All in all, you can either send the `theStatus` parameter as data and let the model binding system to bind it to your action method parameter, or use routing to do that for you. In this latter case, you must either configure a proper routing entry or use a query string like in my modified version.

For the `if` statement to work, you need to send back something that does have a `Success` property, like Fabio did.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not work.. I will accept it as answer so other people can read it too, but i give up. :D

Comment: Edit your post and add the current state of both your action method and client-side call.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Opslaan(string id)
    {
        if(id != null)
            Database.UpdateAanvraagStatusByGuid(Session["Guid"].ToString(), id);
        // do your logic to check if success is true or false
        return Json(new { Success = true, Message = "something" });
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$("#opslaan").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    var theStatus = $('input[name=StatusOptions]:checked').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Aanvraag/Opslaan/ " + theStatus ,
    //data: { 'theStatus': theStatus } ,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success) {
            alert("Uw wijzigingen zijn opgeslagen.");
        } else {
            alert(result.Message);
        }
    }
});
});
```

**EDIT**

Just to see if it works, change the name of the parameter in the Action and Javascript.

Comment: The same thing happens, the post is being sent but 404's.

Comment: Should the parameter string id not be called theStatus?

Comment: Change it just for tests purpose. Remember to change the script too, concatenating the value in the URL. If it works we can rewrite the code in a better way

Comment: It is still giving error 404 in the web browser, not giving errors in the code though.